# TFS 2010: Set color of work item in a query result

Tags: tfs, workitem

is it in someway possible to change the color or appereance of work items in the result list of a query depending on a value of a field? Want to draw my work item titles red for bugs and green for "ideas" and so on ...
Is this possible with native Visual Studio / TFS methods? Or do I have to use external tools for that?

Thanks
Konrad

Comment: Do you mean the query results within VS, or would using the Excel plugin to get results be OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, if you want to, open the query in excel.
Then, you could modify the color of a cell, row or column, based on the value of that (or another cell).

Finally, you should be able to modify the XLST excel template file used to display the query results, so that it will always use the color code.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the XLST template ... will try this

Answer (score 1):

It is a great idea. You can post your suggestion on UserVoice. Microsoft listens to the feedback of the items that get a lot of votes. You can find it at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com.

Using Excel with the conditional formatting is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You tried with http://studiostyl.es/ ?

Muralidharan T R

Comment: This is for code styles and has nothin to do with TFS and its work items.